# Check if resource exists in another application in Delphi

Tags: delphi, resources

I'm trying to verify whether a resource exists in another Delphi application, the problem is that only know how to do it locally, I mean in the application itself.

Source:

```
function exists_resource(name: string): boolean;
begin
  if (FindResource(HInstance, PChar(name), RT_RCDATA) <> 0) then
  begin
    Result := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

As I can verify this in a different application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load the external file.

```
function exists_resource(const name, filename: string): boolean;
var
  HInst: THandle;
begin
  HInst:= LoadLibraryEx(PChar(Filename), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
    //Win32Check(HInst); //Uncomment if you want to generate errors.
    if HInst = 0 then exit(false);
  try
    Exit((FindResource(HInst, PChar(name), RT_RCDATA) <> 0));
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Hinst);
  end; {try}
end;
```

Note that using LoadLibraryEx in this way will work for loading both dll's and exe's.

Comment: Exception block is pointless, FindResource will not raise an exception.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, you're a bit silly now. The `finally` is not there to catch exceptions. It's there to catch the `Exit`.

Comment: Strange. What's wrong with `Result := FindResource...` and not having a tryf?

Comment: It's a coding style, to ensure that resource leaks are not introduced when refactoring.

Comment: It's not `FindResource` that can leak, it's `LoadLibraryEx` that can leak.

Comment: Sure. What kind of refactoring do you have in mind that could make the code exit before the FreeLibrary?

Comment: Why are you getting all worked up about this? It's just a coding style. If you do any real work with the resource you don't have to worry about leaks. What is it you don't get 'bout this. Gheez.

Comment: I was just trying to find the silly in me. If this was a coding style that we put superficial protection blocks here and there to protect resources from the very us at the expense of cluttering and slowing the code, or something really worthy of trying to impose it on beginners and the silly me.